# Need to close below dropdown when click on other popover button

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need to close the dropdown when I click on another popover button

Comment: what you are asking... nobody will understand... Please give more details about your question, what you are trying to achieve, what you have done and what are your researches for the same. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: <div class="dropdown" ng-show="step==2" style="display:inline">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button"

Comment: I need to close this dropdown when i click on another division

Comment: edited my answer... please check once..

Comment: Is your issue solved.. ?

Answer (score -1):

you can try this in many ways:

**simplest** one in angularJs itself by adding a ng-click in your button which will change the value of `show` :

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" ng-click="show=0">
```

otherwise:

you can add some id to your button so it will be captured easily,
e.g.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="hideDropdown">
```

and can try with given solutions:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', function(evt) {
    if($(evt.target).is('#hideDropdown')) {
        // Hide code
        // e.g. show=0;
    } });
```

you can try with 
**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('hideDropdown').onclick = function(e){
        // Hide code
        // e.g. show=0;
}
```

or **AngularJs** itself by using a directive

```
YourApp.directive('testClick', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.onclick = function() {
                //do some thing.
            }
        }
    }
})

*html code*

<button test-click>Test Click</button>
```

you may need to change the conditions as per your requirements as it is a rough code.